# Partial derivatives of components of a vector field

Tags: derivatives, vector-fields

I'm struggling to understand which are the partial derivatives of the component functions of

$$F(x,y,z) = Pi + Qj + Rk$$

This question came up when I looking the solution of the following exercise:

Determine if the the vector field is conservative or not of the following function:
$$F(x,y,z)=y^2z^2i + 2xyz^3j + 3xy^2z^2k$$

The theorem used to solve is:

> If F is a vector field defined on all on $R^3$ whose component functions have continuous partial
> derivatives and curl F = 0, then F is a conservative vector field.

The final answer is yes (since $curl = 0$ and the space is $R^3$, as the book says), but it doesn't show the partial derivatives of $P$, $Q$ and $R$. What is the first derivative of $P$? And the second one?

Comment: You have gotten to this point of the course and you do not know what partial derivatives are?

Comment: @EricTowers thanks, for pointing. Fixed.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know what they are, but I don't know if the first partial derivative of $y^2z^2$ should be $0$, $2yz^2$ or $2y^2z$.

Comment: No, you don’t know. What does first mean here? It means with respect to $x$.  I would never call that first unless my variables were $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In
$$  F(x,y,z) = y^2z^2 i + 2 x y z^3 j + 3xy^2z^2 k  \text{,}  $$
we have (by finding the coefficients of $i$, $j$, and $k$), \begin{align*}
P(x,y,z) &= y^2 z^2  \\
Q(x,y,z) &= 2 x y z^3  \\
R(x,y,z) &= 3xy^2z^2
\end{align*}
Then, for example,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} &= 0  \\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} &= 2y z^2  \\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial z} &= 2y^2 z  \text{.}
\end{align*}
For the $x$ partial derivative, recall that when we treat $x$ as the independent variable, we treat $y$ and $z$ as constants, so this is the derivative of a constant, hence zero.  For the $y$ partial derivative, $y$ is the variable and $z$ is a constant, so the power rule only acts on $y^2$ and the $z^2$ passes through the constant multiple rule.  For the $z$ partial derivative, $z$ is the variable and $y$ is a constant, so the power rule only acts on $z^2$ and the $y^2$ passes through the constant multiple rule.

Comment: I believe I'm making a big confusion here, when the author says the **partial derivatives of a component** he means just one or all of them?

Comment: The components are $P$, $Q$, and $R$.  Each of these has three partial derivatives (in this setting).  So the quoted text is requiring nine functions (three partial derivatives of each of three components) be continuous.

Comment: Then, if he says second partial derivatives of $P, Q,$ and $R$ should I suppose he is talking about 27 (3 * 9) functions?

Comment: Yes, there are $27$ second partial derivatives.